# use autoform to create user register form

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

I used below schema with autoform but my form not shown and return error. How to fix my form based on schema to create user and profile with one form in meteor-autoform.

I was created a schema based on [this example](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#attach-a-schema-to-meteorusers).

Schema:

```
UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name"
    },
    family: {
        type: String,
        label: "Family"
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        label: "Address",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    },
    workAddress: {
        type: String,
        label: "WorkAddress",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Phone Number",
        optional: true
    },
    mobileNumber: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Phone Number"
    },
    birthday: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    }

});
User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
    },
    emails: {
        type: [Object],
        // this must be optional if you also use other login services like facebook,
        // but if you use only accounts-password, then it can be required
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    profile: {
        type: UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
//    // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
//    // Option 1: Object type
//    // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
//    // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
//    // Example:
//    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
//    // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
//    // you will fail validation in some cases.
//    roles: {
//        type: Object,
//        optional: true,
//        blackbox: true
//    }
//    // Option 2: [String] type
//    // If you are sure you will never need to use role groups, then
//    // you can specify [String] as the type
    roles: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    }
});
```

And also this is my autoform code:

```
<template name="addUser">
    {{#autoForm schema=User type="method" meteormethod="addUser" id="addUserForm"}}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>add user</legend>
            {{> afQuickField name='username'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='emails[0].address'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.name'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.family'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.address'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.workAddress'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.phoneNumber'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.mobileNumber'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.birthday'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.gender'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.description'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='roles' type="select" options=rolesTypeOptions}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">register</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

How to fix my form to create user with some profile field in one form?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: what error you are getting? can you share..

Answer (score 0):

When using **Autoform** `schema` option, you need to make sure the schema you are referring to is defined in the scope. The reason your schema is not being displayed is maybe you didn't register a helper for your `User` schema. Try to put the following line under the schema definition you pasted:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.registerHelper('User', User)
}
```

Also, a good reflex to have is to enable **Autoform** & **SimpleSchema** debug mode when developping your app & forms:

```
if (Meteor.isClient)
    AutoForm.debug()
SimpleSchema.debug = true
```

in any development.js file you might have to define your development environment in your app.